# How to do Hibernate XML-Mapping, for one-to-many using 1 PK to map to another Entity with Composite Keys

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I'm having a big problem trying to do map an entity to another that has a Composite-PK...
What i'm trying to achieve here is, 1 User can have many Task, and Each Task contains many Modules and It's Action

| User | (**Userid**, Name) 
 | UserRight | (**Userid**, **TaskId**) 
 | Task | (**TaskId**, **ModuleId**, **ActionId**) 
 | Action | (**ActionId**, ActionName) 
 | Module | (**ModuleId**, ModuleName)

in my User.hbm.xml 
    `<set name="tasklist" table="UserRight" cascade="all">
    <key column="user_id" />
    <many-to-many column="task_id" unique="true"class="kodi.model.UserRights.Task" />
    </set>`

and i receive this error

```
SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key  (FK8AF2ACF15756F47C:UserRight [task_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (task [task_id,submodule_id,action_id])
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[default]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at kodi.gen.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at kodi.gen.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    at kodi.view.LoginAction.<init>(LoginAction.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
```

I know the problem is becoz, i'm trying to only use 1 Attribute to map to a set with 3 but i'm really not sure how to solve it.

can anybody please help?

Comment: why does task have a compositeId? Is TaskId not unique?

Comment: Hi Firo,  Yes u have a point there.. darn!..  but if i'm unable to uniquely identify the task in this case, is there a way i can do for such a mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest and best way would be to make taskid unique and map it as id.

If not possible you can try `<many-to-many property-ref="TaskId"/>` or `<many-to-many property-ref="Id"/>`